# Merging XTS table in R

Tags: r

I would like to merge two xts table and respect the columns header, while adding a column if needed. The `XTS1`  would be :

```
            ABC DEF
1/18/2020   33  25
1/19/2020   34  26
```

`XTS2` would be :

```
            ABC DEF GHI
1/20/2020   35  24  19
```

and the resulting table would be :

```
            ABC DEF GHI
1/18/2020   33  25  0
1/19/2020   34  26  0
1/20/2020   35  24  19
```

The order of the column might change.
Does anybody has a sharp way of fixing this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi please refer below answer hope this will help.

```
XTS1 <- data.frame('ABC'=c(33,34),'DEF'=c(25,26))
XTS2 <- data.frame('ABC'=c(35),'DEF'=c(24),'GHI'=c(19))

XTS <- merge(XTS1,XTS2,by=c('ABC','DEF'),all=T)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tushar,. I didn t know that option actually.